# Is it at all possible to have a Function in VBA Excel that takes arrays as parameters (input) and outputs itself as an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, input, output

Trying to make a Function that will both take in array arguments and will output itself in the end as an array.

Pseudo code:

```
Function CheckCommonPartOfArrays(ByRef arrayA as Variant, ByRef arrayB as Variant) as Variant

    Dim aTemp()
    Dim itemA as Variant
    Dim itemB as Variant
    Dim i 

    For Each itemA in arrayA
        For Each itemB in arrayB
            If itemA = itemB Then
                Redim Preserve aTemp(i)
                aTemp(i) = itemA
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next itemB
    Next itemA

    ' And here is the problem, now trying to copy this
    ' temporary array Temp() into the array CheckCommonPartOfArrays,
    ' which is declared as Variant in the beginning of the function,
    ' but it doesn't work.


    CheckCommonPartOfArrays = aTemp
End Function
```

In the LOCALS window, it seems like CheckCommonPartOfArrays is in fact an array and it DOES contain the elements I want it to, however when I try to copy it into another array OR even debug.print the values, each time I try to call it it calls as function and tells me that 'argument not optional' - meaning the ByRef arrayA as Variant, ByRef arrayB... etc.'

Is there any way to do this?

I would like the function to take in two one-dimensional arrays as arguments, and then in the end I would like the function itself to be the resulting array, which I could use later on in code.

Comment: `Function CheckCommonPartOfArrays(ByRef arrayA as Variant, ByRef arrayB as Variant) as Variant()`

Comment: I would also add a `Exit For` after the `i = i +1`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however it does not seem to change anything! When back to the subroutine I try:
anotherTempArray = CheckCommonPartOfArrays, and instead of copying the output of the Function it calls the function again...

I tried that with () as well, same result :/

Comment: works for me `anotherTempArray` should be declared `Dim anotherTempArray() as Variant` and the call should be `anotherTempArray = CheckCommonPartOfArrays(arrayA,arrayB)`

Comment: Please show the subroutine that calls this.

Comment: You resolved my problem! I called it by : " CheckCommonPartOfArrays arrayA, arrayB " in the subroutine.
This is how i always call other subroutines for example for finding range, I did not know that we could call it in this way (which works thanks to you! ): " anotherTempArray = CompareArray(arrayA, arrayB).

By the way, do you think this is an efficient way to compare arrays?